# Get last Security Checkup date (Google Apps for Business)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

If  you go to [Google's Account Security page](https://myaccount.google.com/security), you can see your own security checkup date:

[image: Security Checkup Screenshot]

How can I:

- Get a list of the last security checkup date, for all users
- Or alternatively, force certain users to go through the security checkup next time they log in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do either of these things programmatically. You can audit some of these things for your users but it would still come back to change management w/ communications and internal policies.

Comment: What is possible to audit?